# How do you stabilize a humbucker pickup with loose screws?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, pick-ups, repair

I tried to disassemble and reassemble my neck pickup because it moves a lot, it looks lower and too much movable, unlike the bridge pickup.

[image]
[image]

The two middle screws of the neck pickup, left, are movable and keen on getting out of their holes. I've tried to stress on that on the picutres by moving them up a bit.

It looks like it's the screws with the springs that are supposed to press on something that raises the mic. But I didn't find anything that "raises" it when disassembling it. Like something to lie on and rise it. I didn't try to disassemble the bridge mic to compare.

Let me know if you need photos/videos or anything else.

Comment: Well… a photo of the other side of **both** pickups would help - so we can see how the 'broken' & the 'working' one are assembled. Sometimes the pickup mounts [especially on vintage guitars] are little more than waxed cardboard, so after a while you need to do some remedial work on the holes. BTW, it's quite common for them to rock back & forth when only supported by 2 central screws [the 4 round the edges hold the frame in place, not the pickup]

Comment: Here they are @Tetsujin ! Thanks for your comment. Okay I understand I need to find some things to replace my pickup mounts

Comment: I would take off the neck pickup ring by undoing the four screws at the corners and see if you can get the pickup rethreaded onto the pickup screws, then put the pickup ring back in. You’ll have to take all the strings off also.

Comment: Photos from the top-side aren't much use. We need to see how it's all assembled. You're unlikely to be able to do this with the strings on.

Comment: I would bet some money that it's the standard humbucker mount with adjustable screw and spring. The spring is probably inside the guitar body or lost, so you really need to disassemble it. You'll see how it works if you unscrew the corners of the bridge pickup and don't touch the center screws. You don't need to completely remove strings with this style of bridge, just slacken them enough that you can pull the stopbar from it's pegs and you can move them aside.

Comment: FWIW, don't be panicky about disassembling everything.  Take a photo at every step so you know how to re-assemble.  Have several small containers on hand to place screws, springs, and other tiny parts that love to run and hide in corners.

Comment: The neck pickup frame is mounted backwards, so someone has already tinkered with it

Answer (score 2):

Looks very much to me like two things:

1. Someone had already disassembled that pickup (which is probably the cause of #2.....), as evidenced by the fact that the pickup ring is mounted 180 degrees in the wrong direction
2. The springs that would 'tension' and stabilize the pickups position are missing, These springs would usually slide overtop of the screw, in between the pickup and the pickup ring.

Comment: agree totally - take the strings off, unscrew the pickup surround and post some pictures of the pickup and mounting ring